# Concatenate two strings in ESP-idf

Tags: c++, eclipse, esp32

```
char AT[2] = "AT";
char AT_COMPLEMENT[4] = "\r\n";
```

How can I join the two strings in ESP-IDF?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm

Answer (score -4):

Actually ESP-IDF uses C, so I fix it with this:

char *AT = "AT";
const char *AT_COMPLEMENT= "\r\n";

char * strcat (char * dest, const char * src)

Comment: You may write your answer in code style.

Comment: esp-idf uses C.

Comment: Your `AT` is a pointer to a string array of 3-byte long (including terminating `\0`), if you `strcat(char* dest, const char* src)` means `strcat(AT, AT_COMPLEMNT)`, you will have an overflow on `AT` array, if may not crash immediately, but it will sooner or later.